# Is it possible to pass props from child component to template?

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

Is this possible?

Send props from child to parent...

**Child.vue**

```html
<template showLogo="false">
    ...
</template>
```

**Parent.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="showLogo">
    <logo>
  </div>
  ....
</template>
```

Comment: You can do it with event. props is unidirectional.  " All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can make your app’s data flow harder to understand." ,quote from offical doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much scoped slots: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

As in your example:

`parent.vue`

```html
<child>
  <template v-slot="{ showLogo }">
    <logo v-if="showLogo">
    </logo>
  </template>
</child>
```

This video is quite helpful on the subject: https://adamwathan.me/the-trick-to-understanding-scoped-slots-in-vuejs/

But I'd recommend reading about slots at first, beware because it's a more advanced pattern.